# Simple class usage+undefined reference

Tags: c++

I have just created this simple class.When I compile, I am getting the following error.

```
caller.o: In function 'main':
caller.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to 'Reader::Reader(int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Reader.h

```
#ifndef READER_H
#define READER_H
class Reader
{
 private:
  int m_month;
  Reader() {}
 public:
  Reader(int month);
 void SetDate(int month);
 int GetMonth() {return m_month;}
 };
 #endif
```

Reader.cpp

```
#include "Reader.h"
Reader::Reader(int month);
{
  SetDate(month);
}
void Reader::SetDate(int month)
{
  m_month=month;
}
```

main program

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
#include "Reader.h"
int main()
{ int i;
  i=5;
  Reader rd(i);
  i=rd.GetMonth();
  cout<<i;
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Is it a linker error?  (Make sure your IDE has all the cpp files included and flagged to be compiled.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `;` semicolon that should not be there.

```
Reader::Reader(int month)//; remove semicolon from this line !!!
{
    SetDate(month);
}
```

Comment: It's called a semi-colon. :-)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It's actually called a "semicolon"; it's not hyphenated.

Comment: Thank you. Now I compile without errors. But When I compile my files, it is creating a.out which is probably my other C project exe file.I do not understand what is happening.h5c++ Reader.cpp main.cpp Then I did h5c++ Reader.cpp main.cpp -o myfirst

Comment: Found out. Some path problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile all your source files into object files, and then link the object files together to produce the program.

This can be done in one step:

```
gcc Reader.cpp main.cpp
```

Or in two separate steps:

```
gcc -c Reader.cpp main.cpp
gcc Reader.o main.o
```

Of course, you should normally have an IDE, Makefile or buildsystem generator (such as CMake) take care of this for you.

Comment: When I compile my files, it is creating a.out which is probably my other C project exe file.I do not understand what is happening.h5c++ Reader.cpp main.cpp